# is any onmousescroll / onmouserollover event exist?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

is there  any onmousescroll / onmouserollover event exist in javascript / asp.net on picklist or select control. I want to implement/attach this event on the picllist of CRM lead form's onload. I will do that. But want to know is any such kind of event exist or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onmousewheel` and `DOMMouseScroll` are events fired for the mouse wheel. `onscroll` is better if you want to catch scrolling, however, and it has better support.  Not sure how it will work with select elements though.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html

*onmouserollover* sounds like you probably want `onmouseenter`, but [unfortunately it's IE only](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#mouseenter).  Your options are to try and simulate it using `onmouseover`, or use a library/framework that does it for you.  [jQuery's](http://jquery.com) `hover()` provides equivalent functionality.

Comment: Andy, can use this in dynamic CRM using javascript?

Comment: @Lalit: I'm not sure how it would fit in with Dynamic CRM because I'm not familiar with the platform. However, as long as you're in control of the JavaScript that is output with each page then you should be able to attach these events to any element within the DOM. You might have better luck if you contact Microsoft Dynamics support and see if they can help you.

Comment: thanks Andy, make me sure about , are these events working in asp.net environment ?

Comment: @Lalit: these are JavaScript events (client-side, run in browser), so it doesn't matter what runs on the server side. In other words, yes, you can use these events (in the client/browser) when you have asp.net environment (on the server).

Comment: @Lalit: What @Piskvor says is true.  Regardless of your server-side environment (PHP, asp.net, Python, etc), these events are available on the client side.  Check the links in my post for browser compatibility.